# What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\root{n}\of {\sin^n{x}+\cos^n{x}}dx=\sqrt 2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\root{n}\of {\sin^n{x}+\cos^n{x}}dx=\sqrt 2.$$

Any hints?

Comment: For $n\to\infty$ the expression $\sqrt[n]{a^n + b^n}$ is just max$(a,b)$.

Comment: With @Winther, I think the last thing you need to justify is exchange limit with the integral (e.g. Fatou's lemma or DCT probably is sufficient).

Comment: @Winther Only if $a,b \geq 0$.

Comment: How can we prove the root of $a^n$ + $b^n$ is equal to the max? Or what is it and where can I find more about it?

Answer (score 1):

Fix a positive integer $n$. Then we have $\cos^n(x) \geq \sin^n(x)$ for $x \in [0,\tfrac{\pi}4]$ and $\sin^n(x) \geq \cos^n(x)$ for $x \in [\tfrac{\pi}4,\tfrac{\pi}2]$. Thus $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \sqrt[n]{\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x)}\,dx \leq \sqrt[n]{2} \int_0^{\pi/4} \cos(x)dx = \frac{\sqrt[n]{2}}{\sqrt2}, \\ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \sqrt[n]{\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x)}\,dx \leq \sqrt[n]{2} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \sin(x)dx = \frac{\sqrt[n]{2}}{\sqrt2},$$ and then $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt[n]{\sin^n(x) + \cos^n(x)}\,dx \leq \sqrt[n]{2} \sqrt{2}.$$ Can you bound below the integral?